# Reactjs request library how to get data asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, request, observable

I am using the following code to fetch data from an API in a react application. It will take time to fetch data and because of that the variables are not getting values. How may I perform an asynchronous observable await operation here? I am so new to react and still unclear how to do it

```
            import React from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import { createStore } from 'redux';

            import App from './App';
            import { reducers } from './reducers/index';
            import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
            var request = require('request');

            var options = {
              url: 'http://localhost:8181/api/oranges',
            }


            function get(options) {
              let data = {};
              request(options, function(error, response, body){
                  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                      data = body;
                      console.log(data)
                  }
              });
              console.log(data)
              return data;
            }
            let p =  get(options);
            console.log(p);
```

Comment: 2 questions; where is your react code? and are you using state managers like redux or mobx?

Comment: @FemiOni yes um using redux cannot post the entire app code in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using redux, move the api call to an action function e.g

```
const callAPIaction = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: API_CALL_INPROGRESS, requestInProgress: true})
  request(apicallconfig)
   .then(response => dispatch ({type: API_CALL_SUCCESS, data: response})
   .catch(err => dispatch({type: API_CALL_ERR, err})
```

then in your connected react class/function you watch for state variables from the store like `requestInProgress`, `data` and `err` to decide what to render. this assumes you have configured `redux-thunk`

Comment: okay, I dont have a clue about the code you have written though thank you @Femi Oni